# How to use grep to list items that do not start with "c"

Tags: grep

In one of my computer science classes, my teacher gave us a file of users: `users.txt`.
The lines of the file look like this:

```
$ head users.txt

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
apache:x:71:71:system user for apache2:/var/www:/bin/sh
ftp:x:73:73:system user for proftpd:/var/ftp:/bin/false
c0407115:x:1501:1000:Alberto Damiao Canelas Fraga:/home/c0407115:/bin/bash
c0407165:x:1502:1000:Alexandre Viriato Morais Magalhaes:/home/c0407165:/bin/bash
c0407110:x:1503:1000:Alvaro Manuel Figueiredo Nunes de Sousa:/home/c0407110:/bin/bash
c0307009:x:1504:1000:Ana Marta Tavares Laranjeira:/home/c0307009:/bin/bash
c0416079:x:1505:1000:Ana Rita Caetano Mourato:/home/c0416079:/bin/bash
c0407137:x:1506:1000:AndrÃ© Brito Coimbra:/home/c0407137:/bin/bash
c0307068:x:1507:1000:AndrÃ© Filipe Rios da Fonseca Alves Modesto:/home/c0307068:/bin/bash
```

And then the teacher askes to do the following:

> Write a command that lists all non-student users (this is, their login doesn't start with c??)

My first approach was the following:

```
$ cat users.txt | grep [^c]*

grep: figures: Is a directory
grep: practice: Is a directory
```

I got this error message relating to some directories on the directory I'm working on.
These are the current files in my directory:

```
$ ls

archive  figures  practice  users.txt
```

Then I tried to do the opposite: using the invert match option:

```
$ cat users.txt | grep -v [c]*
$
```

but this time I got no output. Why did this not work, why did I get that error message, and how can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ... | grep [^c]*
> ```

Here, `[^c]*` is a glob, a filename pattern, similar to e.g. `*.txt`.

The `[^c]` means the same as in regular expressions, i.e. it matches any single character that isn't a `c`. Unlike in regular expressions, `*` matches any number of any characters in globs. So the whole thing matches and expands to any filenames that don't start with a `c`, like all of `archive  figures  practice  users.txt`.

When given a list of arguments, without the `-e` or `-f` options, `grep` takes the first one as a pattern, so the command will look for the string `archive` in the rest of the files. `grep` doesn't process directories by default, so you get errors for those.

You'll need to quote the pattern to have it passed unchanged to `grep` if it contains characters that are special to the shell. Or quote the pattern if there are any special characters, to be on the safe side.

---

As a regular expression, `[^c]*` would match any number  of consecutive characters that are not `c`. But since that includes zero-length matches, `grep '[^c]*'` would match any line.

You'll need to lock the pattern to the start of the line and make it require at least one character.

Since this is an assignment, try these commands, and see if you can find out why they do what they do:

```
grep        c   users.txt
grep -v     c   users.txt
grep       ^c   users.txt
grep -v    ^c   users.txt
grep    '^[^c]' users.txt
grep -v '^[^c]' users.txt
```

(`[c]` is the same as just `c`, so I'll leave out that one. By itself, `^` isn't actually special to the shell, so doesn't need quoting here. Some of the patterns there may be equivalent to some others.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong regular expression.
Here is the correct one:

```
cat ./users.txt | grep -v '^c'
```

You can also do this without using `cat`:

```
grep -v '^c' ./users.txt
```

Comment: but in theory, [^c]* should also work right? we are searching for all strings that don't begin with c

Comment: No. `^` inside `[ ]` doesn't mean "start of string", it means "not". You could use it outside of `[ ]` without the asterisk like this: `^[c]`

Comment: Also I don't think `*` after `[ ]` is correct at all.